# Comparing predictiveness of alternative class definitions using linear regression

Tags: r, regression, inference, multiple-comparisons, model-comparison

I am comparing highly-correlated ways to classify patients as sick (1) or well (0). I want to see whether the way you define sickness impacts how well sickness predicts clinical outcomes.

I have built a linear regression model for each definition of sick to predict a continuous clinical outcome. I would like to determine whether the regression coefficient from each of the models is statistically significantly different from that of each of the other models, in a pair-wise fashion. For example, suppose using definition A leads to a larger positive coefficient than using definition B. This suggests that sickness is a stronger predictor of the outcome under definition A than under definition B. **I want to be able to assess the whether this increase in ability to predict the outcome under definition A is statistically significant. [Edit- note that I am not interested in comparing the fit of the regressions, but rather the size of the coefficient]**

I have defined a 95% confidence interval around each of the coefficients (with lower and upper bounds set to the standard error times qnorm(.025), so one strategy is to just consider any coefficients with overlapping confidence intervals to not be statistically-significantly different. However, I have two concerns:

1. I'm not sure how rigorous this is even in the case of a single comparison, and
2. I'd like to correct for multiple comparisons, and the methods I know to do this require comparing p-values, not confidence intervals.

Here are some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame("defA"=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
             "defB"=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1), 
             "defC" =c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1),
             "outcome"=c(0,2,1,4,2,8,7,9,10,9))
lm.a <- lm(outcome~defA, data=df)
lm.b <- lm(outcome~defB, data=df)
lm.c <- lm(outcome~defC, data=df)
```

Here's how I calculated the confidence intervals:

```
coefA <- summary(lm.a)$coefficients["defA",1]
lowboundA <- summary(lm.a)$coefficients["defA",1] + summary(lm.a)$coefficients["defA",2]*qnorm(.025)
upboundA <- summary(lm.a)$coefficients["defA",1] + summary(lm.a)$coefficients["defA",2]*qnorm(.975)
```

Comment: If you compare the models directly that will tell you which model is better (for some meaning of better). Since they are not nested you need to search for methods to compare non-nested models in R.

Comment: My apologies if it wasn't clear, but my question is not how to determine which is better (that's straightforward). My question is how to rigorously determine the statistical significance of any difference in the regression coefficients. I made the key question bold so this is more clear.

Comment: But I will see if I can come up with anything I didn't find before using 'non-nested' in my search terms. Thank you!

Comment: If the two models differ only in respect of which predictor they contain then if there is a difference between them it must be because one predictor is better than the other.